# ros2 rttest example build error

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i try to use https://github.com/ros2/rttest , but when i want to build the examples, it returns errors when running `make`:

```
rttest/build/include/rttest/rttest.h:29:21: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
   size_t iterations = 0,
                     ^
```

and some other lines with the same style of error ? in rttest.h is a struct, with the first entry with the line of above error ?

including `stddef.h` or changing `size_t` to `unsigned int`, doesnt change anything from the style of error ?

thanks for help
flo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218942/ros2-rttest-example-build-error/) by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 406 on 2015-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seeing as ROS2 is currently only in Alpha status, I recommend you report this directly on the [rttest issue tracker](https://github.com/ros2/rttest/issues).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0